# isset method returns false even when the key is present

Tags: php, swagger-ui, lumen-5.3

I am using lumen integrated with swagger for writing a Rest api.
The issue i am having is, that the **isset()** method of php is returning false,
even when the key in array is present, mentioned is my code.

```
$this->setDataCenterHost(isset($aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_HOST]) ? $aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_HOST] : $aData[self::COL_HOST]);
```

this is the problematic statement

```
isset($aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_HOST])
```

when i echo it like this

```
echo $aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_HOST]
```

it returns **datacenter_host_name**

using the same statement with isset inside **setDataCenterHost** function returns false.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Mentioned is the whole class

```
 class DTDataCenter
{
    const DATACENTER_ID     = 'id';
    const DATACENTER_NAME   = 'name';
    const DATACENTER_IP     = 'ping_ip_address';
    const DATACENTER_HOST   = 'host_name';
    const DATACENTER_ISO    = 'iso2';
    const DATACENTER_LATT   = 'laitude';
    const DATACENTER_LONG   = 'longitude';


    const COL_ID   = 'id';
    const COL_NAME = 'dc_name';
    const COL_IP   = 'ping_ip_address';
    const COL_HOST = 'host_name';


    const TBL_NAME = 'datacenter_';

    protected $_oId;
    protected $_oName;
    protected $_oHost;
    protected $_oIp;


    /**
     * DTProtocol constructor.
     * @param $_oId
     */
    public function __construct($aData)
    {
        $this->setBaiscInfo($aData);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->getJson();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJson()
    {
        return array(
            self::DATACENTER_ID     =>$this->getDataCenterId(),
            self::DATACENTER_NAME   =>$this->getDataCenterName(),
            self::DATACENTER_IP     =>$this->getDataCenterIp(),
            self::DATACENTER_HOST   =>$this->getDataCenterHost()
        );
    }

    public function setBaiscInfo($aData)
    {
        //Helper::dumpAndDie($aData);
        $this->setDataCenterId(isset($aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_ID]) ? $aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_ID] :$aData[self::COL_ID] );
        $this->setDataCenterName(isset($aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_NAME]) ? $aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_NAME] : $aData[self::COL_NAME]);
        $this->setDataCenterIp(isset($aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_IP]) ? $aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_IP] : $aData[self::COL_IP]);
        $this->setDataCenterHost(isset($aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_HOST]) ? $aData[self::TBL_NAME.self::COL_HOST] : $aData[self::COL_HOST]);

        // Helper::dumpAndDie($aData);
    }

    public function setDataCenterId($iId)
    {
        $this->_oId = new DTInteger($iId);
    }

    public function setDataCenterName($sName)
    {
        $this->_oName = new DTString($sName);
    }

    public function setDataCenterIp($sIp)
    {
        $this->_oIp = new DTString($sIp);
    }
    public function setDataCenterHost($sHost)
    {
        $this->_oHost = new DTString($sHost);
    }

    public function getDataCenterId()
    {
        return $this->_oId;
    }

    public function getDataCenterName()
    {
        return $this->_oName;
    }

    public function getDataCenterIp()
    {
        return $this->_oIp;
    }

    public function getDataCenterHost()
    {
        return $this->_oHost;
    }



}
```

Comment: You are not showing enough of your code. So many things can have an effect. So stop being Coy and show all the relevant code

Comment: First thing to remember >>PHP is probably doing the right thing<< Its most likely you are doing something wrong

Comment: @AbraCadaver How else should he access a class constant?

Comment: Is the `echo` in the same class as the `isset()` test?

Comment: You spelt `basic` wrong

Comment: @RiggsFolly you can see the whole class now i have updated the question.

Comment: where is this code being run? I don't see it in your included class

Comment: @cmorrissey inside the setBaiscInfo() method

Comment: @Farkie spelling is not the problem here :)... but thx

Comment: So what is `DTInteger`

Comment: This a another custom class !